# Shortened URLs on Windows domain system

Tags: dns, url, windows-domain

I have a worksystem which is part of a Windows domain. There are certain websites of my organisation that I can access from my system using shorthands URLs, but the same doesn't work from an external device (like my mobile phone).

For example, for website *foobar.myorg.edu*, I can just type "foobar" in the URL bar on the domain-joined system and it works, but I need to give the entire path on an external device. I am not sure how these shorthands are working, but what I have tested is that this is not due to a custom DNS server.

I want to access the website using just "foobar" from my non-domain devices as well since most the internal communication distributes URL assuming you are accessing from internal systems and hence it becomes a pain to modify those URLs the right way every time.

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: You need to add *myorg.edu* as a default dns suffix. How to do it depends on the os: connection properties in Windows, dns-search in some Linuxes...add more details if you need more details.

Comment: Yes, the OS is android. I want to do this on my android mobile phone

Comment: You need to be administrator on Windows, root on Linux; I doubt Android allows to do that if you are not root. There are some [server-side options](https://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2011/02/12/configuring-dns-search-suffixes/) but support is far from universal.